# How do I change Bootstrap 3 div column order on different screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing my 1st responsive design. Is it possible to do this in bootstrap 3 without using hidden-#.

layout on lg and md :

```
[A] [     ]
[B] [  D  ]
[C] [     ]
```

layout on sm:

```
[A][B]
[    ]  
[  D ]
[    ]
[C]
```

layout on xs:

```
[A]
[D]
[B]
[C]
```

Comment: You can't solve this using the Bootstrap grid or grid helper classes like e.g. `.col-sm-push-3`. Duplicating the content of one column (likely _D_) and hiding it on specific viewport sizes is an option, but as you noted you don't want to use e.g. `hidden-xs`.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's push won't solve the issue - Bootstrap does have some limitations and this is one I've run into myself from time to time. The only sure-fire workaround is indeed the hidden-xs with a duplicate version for other screen sizes.

My workaround is to use Foundation Zurb instead, as its source-ordering plugins are better featured for handling this kind of thing! Also you can load in content specifically for certain screen sizes using data-interchange, bypassing the hidden-xs fix entirely :)

Answer (score -1):

you can change your col size for different screen.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">[A]</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">[D]</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">[B]</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">[C]</div>
```

Comment: i know that, but it will note solve the problem, look on my question, colums are switching one too another on different layouts

Comment: its simply impossible to get that result. Its not responsive